# Is it possible to use ETag fully instead cookies for some web applications?

Tags: http, session, cookies, web-applications, etag

The use of cookies in web applications is extremely convenient and universal. But in some countries the law requires to place additional information on a website that uses cookies.

To avoid this in the web application, I consider to use the ETags instead cookies.

I mean mainly about use its to the technical approach, such as maintaining user session, in particular for tasks such as logging and storing information about the state of product basket.

Another advantage ETags instead of cookies in the web application could be:

- Protect from attacks associated with cookies.
- Protect from clearing browser's cookies by user (but not from clearing browser's cache of course ;)

How do you think you can either use ETags instead of cookies?

Is it carries behind an additional risk?

Comment: How would you persist the ETag to be able to pass it in on future calls?

Comment: On the same website or network? Sure, that's possible - just look at the lawsuit [Etsy, AOL, Spotify, and others](http://www.extremetech.com/internet/91966-aol-spotify-gigaom-etsy-kissmetrics-sued-over-undeletable-tracking-cookies) had filed against them about their "undeletable tracking cookies". I'd hesitate, at least until I finished researching the law, before implementing anything in this area myself.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using ETag (cache validator) as a session ID for a public website.  You don't know if multiple clients may be behind a shared cache, which could insert that ETag into a request and cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: Good point @Adrien. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use ETag instead of cookies but not 1-1 and it is not recommended.

They can be a support for cookies.

I have not been able to find legal objections to this issue.